# Adding borders in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make borders around arbitrary cell blocks. Similiar to:

[image]

I figure using the `Label` function in conjunction with `relief='edge'` 
will do the trick. Although, this seems like a very unpythonic and tedious method.
Is there a better way built into tkinter?

Comment: How about http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/labelframe.htm?

Comment: The sample uses the equivalent of tkinter's (tk's) Tk, Frame, LabelFrame, Label, Entry, Button, Radiobutton, Checkbutton, Canvas, and Tree widgets.  'Cell block' is only possibly meaningful in relation to grid geometry, but the sample appears to also use the equivalent of pack and maybe even place.  You should post minimal code for a much simpler window that does not work and say what is wrong and ask how to fix.

Comment: @keven  thanks, this is what I was looking for